# C# Spring Social Twitter - Posting Emoji's?

Tags: c#, twitter, emoji, spring-social-twitter

I am using Spring Social Twitter in a project at the moment and everything is going well. Status update's post and there's no issues. I'm not 100% sure if it's possible but does anybody know if you can use this API to post Emoji's to Twitter?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is yes. All the [common encodings](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) support the full Unicode code-point space, ["the range 0hex to 10FFFFhex"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), and if the API supports c# strings then it supports UTF16 basically. E.g., the c# string `"\u2764"` maps to the Unicode character whose code point is "2764" (which is a heart, ❤). You likely can simply do, `API.PostTwitterMessage("Hello friends! \u2764")` and the tweet should show "Hello friends! ❤".

Comment: Thanks @Quantic you were correct. My mistake was the Emoji's I was trying to use was from a website listing it as \U+2764. My misunderstanding but all sorted now. Thank you for your help.